# Is opencv API cv::cuda::cvtColor() feasible to extend by myself to support UYVY to RGB conversion?

Tags: opencv, colors

I've found that cv::cuda::cvtColor() doesn't support all the color spaces. It only supports maybe half the color spaces known to be supported by cv::cvtColor()

```
cv::cvtColor(raw_mat, bgr_mat, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY);
```

This code above works well, but

```
cv::cuda::cvtColor(gpu_raw_mat, gpu_bgr_mat, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY);
```

This code above doesn't work. Because cv::cuda::cvtColor() doesn't include a conversion function for cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY.

So I looked other functions for other color spaces like cv::CV_YUV2BGR. It is YUV_to_BGR(). From my seeing this function, I think I could implemet one for cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY myself. I guessed it would be similar to YUV_to_BGR().

Can I easily implement it?
For me to do this, don't you have any information I can study? If it is possible I wish I impelemt one and contribute the new API.

Comment: dig into OpenCV's source code then. the cuda modules are in `opencv_contrib`. you'll find cuda kernels in the `.cu` files, and the use of them in `.cpp` files. -- https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/How_to_contribute

Comment: @Christoph I will try to implement one. If successfuly completed, I will contribute it. Thank you.